# Is this "New Contributor" thing even helping?

Tags: discussion, new-users, new-contributor-indicator

I saw a new contributor question today. The post doesn't show any effort done by the OP and also doesn't contain any code, images or anything.

I still tried to help it out by asking him to post what he tried, relevant images and bit more explanation.

But in span of few minutes, even before the OP could reply to my comment, their question was put on hold as *too broad*.

Now I am not saying that putting the question *on hold* is wrong but that that makes the whole **"New Contributor"** feature a waste.

Comment: Who said that the new banner was about not closing off-topic questions?

Comment: It is meant to help users self-regulate in other interactions with new users. Language used, mostly (if not exclusively).

Comment: Er... it was put On Hold, but then the asker can still respond to your comment, right?

Comment: Just because the question is closed, doesn't mean that your comment went to waste. If the question is improved enough by OP, then it will get reopened.

Comment: @yivi well no language is required in case of closing and downvoting questions.

Comment: My point exactly.

Comment: But my point here is no one actually tried to help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you were trying, weren't you?

Comment: @VivekMishra I think you are mistaken as to what the "new contributor" badge means.  It doesn't mean "you must help this person" or "don't downvote" or "don't vote to close".  It means "be mindful of the language you are using when communicating with this person because they are new to the site."

Comment: @yivi I am still trying

Comment: @psubsee2003 in case of these types of questions, generally there are no communications, its just votes and flags

Comment: @VivekMishra ok, but that doesn't change what the badge is intended to mean.  Off-topic is still off-topic regardless of whether the user is new or not

Comment: @Vivek these flags can get the question closed, which points the OP to our help center. How is that not helpful? The badge is just there so people remember to be nice, **if** they comment. Doesn't say they have to comment, or that we have to allow questions that would otherwise be off topic or not up to our standards

Comment: I assume [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003266/how-can-i-make-splash-screen-activity-like-spotify-app) is the question you were referencing.  This is in no way on-topic.  It's going to take a lot of work by the OP to make it on-topic.  So being on-hold is the right status.  But if the OP fixes the question, it can be reopened,

Comment: @psubsee2003 I know it requires a lot of work to make it on topic but no one except me told him on how to make it on topic.

Comment: As Patrice [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373008/is-this-new-contributor-thing-even-helping#comment623989_373008), the on-hold banner have links to a lot of helpful information.

Comment: From a personal p.o.v. I refrain from posting help comments if someone else is already putting out said comments. Otherwise the comment section will get cloggy and possibly overwhelming for the OP. (CC @ nobody else was helping in the comments)

Comment: Now From my point of view for future references should I try helping in these type of questions or not

Comment: If you think you can help, and are willing... why not?

Comment: @Vivek entirely up to you. The badge and banner for we contributor just means to be mindful of being polite. For the rest it's as it always was: entirely up to the level of effort you are willing to invest. If you want to help more than a simple flag or close vote,have at it

Comment: If that 'Spotify' Q. gets cleaned up enough to be acceptable, I'll eat my dog.  It's just not going to happen.  The OP's never improve such requirement-dump questions and, even if someone was to provide a massive, detailed answer, I can guarantee that the OP would not understand it, even with a trail of help-vamp blood a mile long:(

Comment: @VivekMishra I'd rather see you ask them for code than for an image. With an image, it's still a zero-effort requirement dump. With code, it has a show of effort.

Comment: I proposed a method for evaluating the utility of the New Contributor Indicator on the Meta Stack Exchange, with the hope that the SE Devs aren't foolhardy enough to throw an annoying feature like this onto the site without any concept of how to judge if it's working or not, but I wanted to make sure that they are aware that we want actionable data to come out of it, not just a "We thought this might help. Is it helping? We don't know" kind of eventual response.

Comment: The Meta SE Feature request I posted was: [Let's use the Snark Detector to actually find out if the Contributor Indicator is having any effect where we want it to.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314563/363946)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The stream of new questions is now a show of black hands. Blackhanders tend to post poor questions, so the icon naturally acquires the meaning of "prepare to down/close vote", as surely as a yellow traffic light means "prepare to stop"

But it probably helps someone at SO management feel better about themselves, so there is that.

Comment: This seems much relatable

Comment: The "New contributor" banner might go over better, if it simply pointed out that new users may not understand our many rules. Instead of hammering on the CoC and the Be Nice thing.

Answer (score 22):

It's probably too early to have meaningful metrics on the impact the "new contributor" banner is or it is not having.

Hopefully in some time we'll get a new blog post telling us about its impact, although measuring these things is not always easy.

The way I see it, the *new contributor indicator* is there simply to help users to be aware that the user they are interacting with may not be completely familiar with the many rules and vagaries of the platform, and to try to make an effort to be extra kind and welcoming when communicating with this user (for example, when explaining said rules).

Considering this, the impact should not be measured in **off-topic questions not being closed**, but in **less flags being raised because existing users successfully self-regulate** when communicating with new contributors.

What it does not mean is *"SO rules do not apply to this user, because they are new"*. So voting should proceed as always: **vote the content, not the user**.

That a question you were posting a comment to was put on hold does not mean the new banner is working or not (nor I think it should be related this at all).

Comment: My experience has been the opposite of the OP.  I see many "New Contributor" questions that are upvoted with clear problems.  The most recent had posted code and output from code which didn't match.  The output didn't even show the problem described in the question.  This question had multiple upvotes.  After a few minutes enough of us commented and downvoted to even things out.  I cannot agree more with your statement "vote the content, not the sure"